# qsort not giving proper result while sorting 2D points

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to sort the points in 2d space w.r.t to an origin.Here is the code:

```
double distSq(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return static_cast<double>((p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) +
      (p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y));
}

int orientation(Point p, Point q, Point r)
{
        double signedArea = double((q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) - (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y));

        if (signedArea == 0) return 0;  // colinear
        return (signedArea > 0)? 1: 2; // clock or counterclock wise
}

int compare(const void *vp1, const void *vp2)
{
       Point *p1 = (Point *)vp1;
       Point *p2 = (Point *)vp2;

       // Find orientation
       int o = orientation(origin, *p1, *p2);
       if (o == 0)
         return (distSq(origin, *p2) >= distSq(origin, *p1))? -1 : 1;

       return (o == 2)? -1: 1; 
}

int  main()
{
    int n;
    n = 10;
    Point p[n];
    int i,xx,yy;
    srand(time(NULL));

    p[0].set(1,1);
    p[1].set(1,5);
    p[5].set(5,4);
    p[4].set(4,2);
    p[3].set(2,1);
    p[2].set(3,5);
    p[6].set(2,3);
    p[7].set(4,3);
    p[8].set(3,4);
    p[9].set(3,2);

    cout << "\nThe input points are \n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout << p[i];

    origin=findInterior(p,n);
    cout << "\n\nThe origin is: " << origin << endl;
    qsort(&p[0],n,sizeof(Point),compare);
    cout << "\nThe sorted points are: \n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout << p[i];
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The `findInterior()` function finds any point interior to the convex hull formed for these points. The problem in `qsort` doesn't give correct sorted order of points for some origin like `(2,2)`.
eg:

```
origin(3.33333,3)

sorted order: (4,3)(5,4)(3,5)(3,4)(1,5)(2,3)(1,1)(2,1)(3,2)(4,2)
```

which is correct. But for

```
origin(2,2)
```

i get

```
(3,2)(4,3)(5,4)(3,4)(2,3)(1,5)(1,1)(2,1)(4,2)(3,5)
```

which is not correct. There are many such points for which wrong sorted order comes. The Point class has `(x,y)` in `double` data type. Can anyone tell me why is this error coming?

Comment: If programming in C++, you should probably be using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of old arrays (especially since C++ doesn't support [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)), and also I'd recommend [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead.

Comment: Don't use `qsort`. The c++ standard library has type-safe sorting algorithms that will probably work better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will edit the code so as to use std::sort. I was just not able to figure out where this code was going wrong.

Comment: Why are you static_casting? If whatever Point::x is is not a double that's kind of a recipe for disaster.

Also as Story Teller said above, use std::sort instead. It's generally faster and typesafe.

Comment: Also try to improve the indentation. It helps humans to better read that and help you.

Comment: Also what you could try is sorting at insertion; ```std::set``` of points sorts every time you insert something! it will insert the points using a binary tree which leads to the same performance order like you have with quick sort. You can bind a comparator to the std::set as well.

Comment: I am not sure that your `orientation` function establishes weak ordering. I have a suspiction that it is not transitive.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `orientation` function. It is not transitive: if `a > b` and `b > c` then `a` is not always greater than `c`. THis is the problem: you cannot have any meaningful order if your comparison function is not transitive.

Proof of nontransitivity:

```
#include <cassert>

struct Point 
{
    double x, y;
};

Point origin{0,0};

double distSq(Point p1, Point p2)
{ /* Skip */ }

int orientation(Point p, Point q, Point r)
{ /* Skip */ }

int compare(const void *vp1, const void *vp2)
{ /* Skip */ }

int  main()
{
    Point a {5, 0}, b{-5, -5}, c{-5, 5};
    assert(compare(&a, &b) > 0 && "sanity assertion 1");
    assert(compare(&b, &c) > 0 && "sanity assertion 2");
    assert(compare(&a, &c) > 0 && "Transitivity violation");
}
```

> Assertion failed!
>
> Expression: compare(&a, &c) > 0 && "Transitivity violation"

Comment: Is there any way I can remove this fault? I guess even if I use std::sort (as suggested in comments below the question) and use this compare function, I will not get correct sorted output.

Comment: @shane You might want to define what you mean by "correct". Would [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space#Examples) be correct? If yes, use it. In no, please explain (to yourself, as well as to others) why.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your first example is wrong too. Maybe you need functions like `compare` or `orientation` for some other purpose, but you don't need them to sort some points by their distance from an origin.

Besides your `compare` function calculate a distance only if the points are collinear and in `orientation` the line `if (signedArea == 0) ...` is prone to rounding errors due to floating point approximation.

To sort a number of points with respect to their distance from a given point you can use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::pair;

struct Point {
    double x, y;
    void set( double xx, double yy ) {
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &o, const Point &p ); 
};

std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream & o, const Point &p ) {
    return o << '(' << p.x << ',' << p.y << ')';    
}

double distSq( const Point &p1, const Point &p2) {
    return (p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y);
}

// sort the vector of points by distance from a point
void sort_points( vector<Point> &vp, Point &o ) {
    // create a temp vector of pairs to store distances (calculated once)
    vector<pair<double,const Point*>> dist_pts;
    for ( auto && i : vp ) {
        dist_pts.push_back(std::make_pair(distSq(o,i),&i));
    }
    // sort pairs using a lambda
    std::sort(dist_pts.begin(),dist_pts.end(),
        []( pair<double,const Point*> &a, pair<double,const Point*> &b) -> bool {
            return a.first < b.first;
        });
    // reorder the original vector
    vector<Point> temp(vp.size());
    for ( auto && i : dist_pts ) {
        temp.push_back(*i.second);
        // show the ordered points and distance, only for testing
        cout << *i.second << ' ' << std::setprecision(6) << sqrt(i.first) << '\n';
    }
}

int  main()
{
    vector<Point> points{ {1,1}, {1,5}, {5,4}, {4,2}, {2,1},
                    {3,5}, {2,3}, {4,3}, {3,4}, {3,2} };

    Point origin{3.3333,3};
    cout << "Origin: " << origin << '\n';
    sort_points(points,origin);

    origin.set(2,2);
    cout << "\nOrigin: " << origin << '\n';
    sort_points(points,origin);

}
```

The order of the sorted points become:

```
Origin: (3.3333,3)
(4,3) 0.6667
(3,4) 1.05408
(3,2) 1.05408
(4,2) 1.20187
(2,3) 1.3333
(5,4) 1.94368
(3,5) 2.02758
(2,1) 2.40368
(1,1) 3.07316
(1,5) 3.07316

Origin: (2,2)
(2,1) 1
(2,3) 1
(3,2) 1
(1,1) 1.41421
(4,2) 2
(4,3) 2.23607
(3,4) 2.23607
(1,5) 3.16228
(3,5) 3.16228
(5,4) 3.60555
```